# On select item close dropdown in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have dropdown which is `TimePicker`, you have options to choose times like `1: 00 am` and so on...

I implement that when you clickoutside dropdown is closed.

Now I have problem close dropdown when user select some option:

On click item in dropdown i call this:

```
 onClick={(e) => {
   handleSelect(time, timeState);
   this.closeTimePicker();
 }}
```

This closeTimePicekr set state on false:

```
closeTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpenTimePicker: false });
  };
```

Problem is  `closeTimePicker()` function is called but does not change state to false.

This is code of entire `TimePicker` - component:

```
class TimePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpenTimePicker: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.handleClickOutside(e));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.handleClickOutside(e));
  }

  setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }

  handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.closeTimePicker();
    }
  };

  openTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpenTimePicker: true });
  };

  closeTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpenTimePicker: false });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      timeState, timeOptions, timeInput, handleChange, handleSelect
    } = this.props;
    const { isOpenTimePicker } = this.state;

    return (
      <div ref={(node) => this.setWrapperRef(node)} onClick={this.openTimePicker} role="button">
        <input
          className="time-picker-input"
          value={timeInput}
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleChange(e, timeState);
            this.closeTimePicker();
          }}
        />
        {isOpenTimePicker ? (
          <ul className="time-list">
            {timeOptions.map((time) => (
              <li
                className={`time-list-item ${timeInput === time ? 'time-list-item-active' : ''}`}
                key={time}
              >
                <a
                  value={time}
                  className="time-list-item-btn"
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    handleSelect(time, timeState);
                    this.closeTimePicker();
                  }}
                  role="button"
                >
                  {time}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ) : (
          ''
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TimePicker;
```

**How to make `closeTimePicker()` function to change state?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add event.stopImmediatePropagation in your `closeTimePicker` method.

The problem here is, the method `openTimePicker` is getting called twice, because it is the parent element of the target element.

```
onClick={(e) => {
                    handleSelect(time, timeState);
                    this.closeTimePicker(e);
                  }}
```

and in `closeTimePicker` method,

```
closeTimePicker = event => {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.setState({ isOpenTimePicker: false });
}
```

Comment: I am getting error that `stopImmediatePropagation` does is undefiend on event, do you know why?

Comment: Actually eorros is this; `TypeError: e.stopImmediatePropagation is not a function`

Comment: @MarkJames are you passing the event as param when calling `this.closeTimePicker(e)` ?

Comment: Yes I did: 
 `onClick={(e) => {
                    handleSelect(time, timeState);
                    this.closeTimePicker(e);
                  }}`
 and  function `  closeTimePicker = (e) => {
    this.setState({ isOpenTimePicker: false });
  };`

Comment: Can you `console.log(e)`, in the `closeTimePicker` and check if it logs Event object?

Comment: He logs MouseEvent: `MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 730, screenY: 519, clientX: 730, clientY: 385, …}`

Comment: Then `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` should work :/ . Write it above `this.setState({ isOpenTimePicker: false });` .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: I change it to `e.stopPropagation();` and it works. THANK YOU!

Comment: stopPropagation will prevent any parent handlers from being executed stopImmediatePropagation will prevent any parent handlers and also any other handlers from executing

Answer (score 1):

**Consider these steps:**

1. At your function `handleChange` which comes from the parent element, define a new parameter `cb`: `handleChange = (e, timeState, cb)`.
2. Supposing that your `handleChange` changes the state of the parent component, or dispatches an event to set the new data came from the event into a state, you should add this line to it `cb && cb()` for example:

```
handleChange = (e, timeState, cb) => {
  this.setState(() => {/*change state*/}, () => {
    cb && cb() //will fire after the state has changed.
  })
}
```

3. The callback we are passing to `handleChange` is `this.closeTimePicker`, thus:

```
        <input
          className="time-picker-input"
          value={timeInput}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, timeState, this.closeTimePicker())}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Current component scope is not accessible inside "closeTimePicker()" function.
        Here,"this" refers to current clickable element and "setState()" method is not available inside "this",
    because of that reason state is not getting updated.
        So, bind the component scope to "closeTimePicker()" function inside constructor.

```
    please refer the below block of code 

        class TimePicker extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
              this.closeTimePicker = this.closeTimePicker.bind(this);
          }
        }
```

Comment: He doesnt need to `bind` the function since ES6 Arrow Function Declaration was used.